# React-redux mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps not working

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I just started learning Redux and cannot figure out this bug.

Here's my code:

```js
// App.js

import React from "react";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import rootReducer from "../reducers";
import CartContainer from "../containers/CartContainer";

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <div>
        <CartContainer />
      </div>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

```js
// reducers/index.js

import { ADD_TO_CART, CHECKOUT } from "../actions";

const initialState = {
  products: [
    { id: 1, name: "iPhone X", price: 99.99, quantity: 5 },
    { id: 2, name: "Macbook Pro 2019", price: 299.99, quantity: 2 },
    { id: 3, name: "Apple AirPods", price: 169.99, quantity: 3 },
    { id: 4, name: "iPad Air 3", price: 349.99, quantity: 1 },
    { id: 5, name: "iPhone X Case", price: 19.99, quantity: 12 }
  ],
  cart: [],
  totalBalance: 0
};

export default function rootReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART:
      const stateProduct = state.products.find(p => p.id === action.productId);

      return {
        products: state.products.map(p => {
          if (p.id === action.productId)
            return {
              ...p,
              quantity: p.quantity - 1
            };
          return p;
        }),
        cart: [
          ...state.cart,
          {
            name: stateProduct.name,
            price: stateProduct.price
          }
        ],
        totalBalance: state.totalBalance + stateProduct.price
      };
    case CHECKOUT:
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: [],
        totalBalance: 0
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

```js
// CartContainer.js

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Cart from "../components/Cart";

const checkout = () => {
  return {
    type: CHECKOUT
  };
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    items: state.cart
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    checkout: () => dispatch(checkout())
  };
};

const CartContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Cart);

export default CartContainer;
```

```js
// Cart.js

import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

export default function Cart({ items, checkout }) {
  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {items.map((item, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{`${item.name}: ${item.price}`}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <button onClick={checkout}>Checkout</button>
    </>
  );
}

Cart.propTypes = {
  items: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      price: PropTypes.number.isRequired
    }).isRequired
  ).isRequired,
  checkout: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

For some reason, my Cart component is not receiving `items` or `checkout` from the CartContainer. I have 2 other components that have very similar functionality and are both working perfectly. What am I missing? I think it either has something to do with initializing cart as an empty array in the initial state or my mapDispatchToProps function but I'm not for sure.

Comment: Just for comparison, can you show where you're importing and using `CartContainer` ? It would also help if you can show where you're creating the store.

Comment: @markerikson hope the above edit helps clarify

Comment: Hmm.  So far it seems valid. I don't see any obvious errors, and the imports and usage seem to line up correctly.  Any chance you can show the `Cart` component as well?

Comment: @markerikson I added Cart as well

Comment: I have to say I'm very genuinely confused. The code _looks_ like it's correct. The variable names and the imports all match up correctly.  If you add a `console.log()` line in your `mapState`, is that even running?  Can you try logging `state` there?  If you log the variables in the component, are they truly `undefined`?  Can you try using the React DevTools Extension to view the `Cart` component and see what it thinks the props are?  (I have some style suggestions, but I want to save those until after the actual issue is fixed.)